# method does not override or implement a method from a supert type - react native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to disable screenshot on my react native app.
The way I am doing is by adding

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
        );
  }
```

**My complete file**

```
package com.xxxxx;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
        );
  }

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.***.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**but i get the following error**

```
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supert
ype
  @Override
  ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `onCreate()` in the `Application` class is

```
public void onCreate()
```

So there is no `Bundle` parameter.

You need to fix your declaration of `onCreate()`

Comment: how will the final code look like ? there are twice onCreate()

Comment: Ah, I see. You are trying to set the `FLAG_SECURE` on the `WindowManager`. You need to do that in the `Activity` class, not in the `Application` class. Move the `onCreate(Bundle ...)` method to your `Activity` class.